# How to extract the result of json with Codable

Tags: json, swift, google-api

I'm using Codable for the first time and want to output the json result of Google Places details as a label.
However, when I print it, the console says "The data could n’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.”.
I can't solve it by myself, so please tell me how to write it correctly.

Thanks.

The result of json

```
{
"html_attributions": [],
"result": {
"formatted_phone_number": "XXXX-XXX-XXX",
"website": "https://www.xxxxx.com/xxxxxx/"
},
"status": "OK"
}
```

Detail.swift

```
import Foundation


struct Details : Codable {
    var formatted_phone_number : String!
    var website : String!
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

fetchDetailData {(details) in
            for detail in  details{
                print(detail.website)
            }
            
        }
}

func fetchDetailData(completionHandler: @escaping ([Details]) -> Void){
        let url = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=\(place_id)&fields=formatted_phone_number,website&key=\(apikey)")!
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){
            (data,respose, error)in
            guard let data = data else{ return }
            do {
                let detailsData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Details].self, from: data)
                completionHandler(detailsData)
            }
            catch{
            let error = error
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
            }.resume()
        }
```

Comment: Is that your complete json? And do `print(error)` instead in the `catch` clause for a more informative error message. _edit_, I see now you have a level above the keys you want to access so create another struct to hold your Detail struct. You can always use the site quicktype.io to get help with your custom types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the issues there is that result is a dictionary not an array. You need also to decode the root structure to extract the result from it. Note that you can also change the website type from String to URL:

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let htmlAttributions: [String]  // make sure to define the proper type in case the collection is not empty
    let result: Result
    let status: String
}

struct Result: Codable  {
    let formattedPhoneNumber: String
    let website: URL
}
```

---

```
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    let result = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data).result
    print(result)
} catch { 
    print(error) 
}
```

This will print

> Result(formattedPhoneNumber: "XXXX-XXX-XXX", website: https://www.xxxxx.com/xxxxxx/)

Comment: I really appreciate your great support! I was able to see the result.

Answer (score 0):

could you try this;

```
struct Place {
let result: Details?
}

struct Details: Codable {
    let phoneNumber: String?
    let website: String?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case website
    case phoneNumber = "formatted_phone_number"
}
}
```

and parse Place.self

you will also need to change "@escaping ([Details])" to "@escaping (Place)"